# Image View OnTouchListener not working properly?

Tags: android, image, imageview, ontouchlistener

Hi I have loaded dynamically images in different position using single image view instance.
my problem is if I touch particular image second image also affected 1st I wish to find which image is touched. i want to print which image is touched. I am suffer in this task please help me.

my problem is i have only one imageview to show all images in appropriate location. I received xml file that xml contain everything like image size, image position ...etc I am loading dynamically images because i receive xml file dynamically. if i touch one image i wish to identify which image is clicked in the design that's all

This is my screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Where do you add the event listener?

Comment: your source code is incomplete... How do you put the two images? What you mean by single ImageView instance? The source code you show correctly adds one imageview to the layout...

Comment: `loaded dynamically images in different position using single image view instance` - if you set onTouchListener on this one instance that has both images in it, then both images will be affected

Comment: @Konstantin i have updated my full code : i received xml file from server...using dom parser and showing images in correct location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firtly implements onTouchListener then override the method,

```
ImageView one = ....
ImageView two = ....
one.SetTag("ITEM ONE");
two.SetTag("ITEM TWO");

one.setOnTouchListener(this);
two.setOnToucListener(this);

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(v == one)
    {
       Log.e("Touched Itemd: ",(String) v.getTag().toString());
    }
    if(v == two)
    {
       Log.e("Touched Itemd: ",(String) v.getTag().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this but my problem is i have only one imageview to show all images in appropriate location. I received xml file that xml contain everything like image size, image position ...etc I am loading dynamically images because i receive xml file dynamically. if i touch one image i wish to identify which image is clicked in the design that's all

Comment: @Balaji: you cant have only one ImageView to show several images. Everytime you call new ImageView() a new one is created. I think your problem lies in basic understanding of java.